# Open a KMZ file in google maps, but only for trusted (authenticated) users in PHP

Tags: php, google-maps, kmz

I know that it's possible to open a KMZ or KML file in browser with google maps with an url like this:

```
https://maps.google.it/maps?q=http://myserver.com/mymap.kmz
```

But I would like to let only authenticated users open that kmz.
To do that, I protected my kmz folder with .htaccess, I coded a php page that checks if the user is logged in and only after that check is passed, it returns the kmz file:

```
...
if(isset($_SESSION['trusted'])) {
    if(isset($_GET['map']) && $_GET['map']!="") {
        $map = $_GET['map'];
        readfile("./kmz/$map");
}
...
```

So, now my url is:

```
https://maps.google.it/maps?q=http://myserver.com/requestkmz.php?map=mymap.kmz
```

The problem seems to be that the file that php returns with readfile is not identical to the original one in file system. Do I need to put an header or specify an encoding?

---

**UPDATE**

I've added an header to the php file, but I've got the same result: KMZ generated is not valid as is the orginal. This is the header added before the readfile line:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kmz');
header("Content-Disposition: inline");
header("Content-Description: KMZ data intended for Google Earth");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to the KMZ-file comes from google, not from the user(when you take a look at console->network you'll see that there isn't any request to the KMZ-file).

So the only "user" that needs to be authorized is google.

Means: it's not possible(except you pass the credentials needed to authenticate the user via the KMZ-URL, but this of course would be insecure )

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't think about that, but you are right: is google to do the request.
Anyway, do you think that there is another way or workaround to let google maps open my kmz but not to let them be public?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea